# 'innerHTML' undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

Preciso de ajuda, não consigo fazer funcionar.

```
var valu=document.getElementsByClassName("user-coins-value middle-block")[0];
var yesno=confirm("You have access key ?");
if(yesno==true)
    {
    var enter_key=prompt("Enter access key",'Example: 43ML9923');
    if(enter_key==".")
        {
        alert("OK\nNotice in 5 seconds!");
        setTimeout(function()
            {
            var enter_coins=prompt("Enter value of coins",'Min: 1000, Max: 75000');
            var timer=setInterval(function()
                {
                var i=document.getElementsByClassName("user-coins-value middle-block")[0].innerHTML;
                i++;
                valu.innerHTML=i++;
                if(valu.innerHTML==enter_coins)
                    {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    alert("It's all\nGood buy")
                }
            }
            ,25)
        }
        ,5000)
    }
    else
        {
        alert("Wrong ACESS KEY")
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde estás a iniciar/declarar essa variável `i`?

Comment: eu declarei acima da primeira linha, porém esqueci de copiar ela aqui.

Comment: Testei seu código e não deu nenhuma falha. Aonde está dando esse erro? Ah, fiquei em dúvida com relação ao i++, tu queria fazer o q ali? iniciar com 0 e ir incrementando a cada interval?

Comment: Sim, a cada intervalo ir aumentando o valor. Está dando erro aqui ''  var i=document.getElementsByClassName("user-coins-value middle-block")[0].innerHTML; ''

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está funcionando perfeitamente, o que vc tem que garantir é que o HTML não contenha nenhum espaço ou outro tipo de caractere que não seja número dentro.
Exemplo: se o seu código estiver assim:

```
  <div class="user-coins-value middle-block">
     5
  </div>
```

Mude para:

```
 <div class="user-coins-value middle-block">5</div>
```

Comment: Ele está certinho, mas continua dando o erro após inserir o valor de 1000 à 75000.